# Sorting high-scores in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Hello I am writing a game using javascript that takes the user's name as well as the "round" they made it to and stores it in two different arrays, and I would like to display the names coupled with the scores, highest to lowest but I'm stumped on how to do it, I can sort the rounds from highest to lowest but I can't figure out how to sort the names along with them. Please help!

my current code:

```
        nameScore.push(username);
        highScore.push(round);
        highScore.reverse();

        for (var i = 0; i < highScore.length; i++) {
            $("#highScore").append(nameScore[i] + "  " + highScore[i] + "<br>");
        }
```

Comment: You are pushing a value into the array and then reversing the array. If you do this multiple times you'll end up with scores on alternating ends of the array. Why are there two arrays? They don't seem to be kept in sync (i.e. the index from one does not appear to match the index in the other).

Comment: Can you show a sample of arrays ? Just to be sure

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Have one object array and sort (a copy of) it before showing

Comment: @Chase No. Keeping them in sync is my problem, I'm struggling to figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use two arrays that are not linked in any way. Just use one array.

```
const userScores = [];

// Play game, get score

userScores.push({username, roundNumber, score});
```

Now you can search/sort this array and the username, the round number, and the score value are all linked together.

Answer (score 0):

There are many suggestions in Stackoverflow on handling the synchronous sorting of several arrays. One idea that came to my mind is the creation of a sorted index array for stepping through the concerned arrays, that are left unsorted. Here is a short example with array `nam`, containing names and array `num` with the associated scores. The function `mkidx(arr)` expects the array to be sorted after as an argument (I chose `num`) and returns a sorted (in descending order) index array that can then be used to step through all unsorted arrays:

```js
var nam=['eins','zwei','drei'];
var num=[10,200,30];

// create an index array:
const mkidx=arr=>arr.map((v,i)=>
({v,i})).sort((a,b)=> typeof a.v=="string"? a.v.localeCompare(b.v) : b.v-a.v).map(v=>v.i);

mkidx(num).forEach(k=>
console.log(k,nam[k]+': '+num[k])
)
```

I created the index-creation function such that it checks for the type of elements and then sorts either alphabetically (`.localeCompare()`) or numerically (descending).